# Can't mount NTFS partition

Tags: mount, ntfs, windows-8

Well, I have Windows 8 running on another partition. I had Ubuntu 11.10 and was running perfectly, I could mount the windows partition.

Now, it says that the partition is hibernated. But it is not. I have tried this line:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda3 /media/9A36761B3675F89
```

I didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a reboot.  I also had this problem, but after I rebooted, I can mount NTFS partitions.

Answer (score 1):

You can just type "ntfs" instead of "ntfs-3g".
Like this `mount -t ntfs /dev/sda3 /media/9A36761B3675F89` .

Comment: Well I have tried that but did not work. But, I have solved it. 

I just run: mount /f  on Windows. Seems like the hibernated file was still there after shuting down.

Answer (score 1):

Had, the same problem with Windows 8, and solved by switch off option of fast power on, that as I think creates a hibernation file.

Answer (score 0):

You can
a) turn off fast-boot in Windows 8 which puts the NTFS partitions in a semi hibernated state or
b) format shared partitions as FAT32 or exFAT(you need to have the necessary drivers installed in Ubuntu for exFAT)

Answer (score 0):

use **sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXX**
as **sdXX** is the drive name that should fix the file system permissions then try to open the drive "mounting it"
I will be waiting for replay if it worked or not